# Why is this very simple LaTeX document can not be compiled?

Tags: luatexja

LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{ltjsarticle}
\begin{document}
Q.
\end{document}
```

Version:

- LuaLaTeX: 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)
- LuaTeXJa: 2017-04-01

Output:

```
$ lualatex t.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./t.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3
(using write cache: /Users/t/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cac
he/generic)(using read cache: /Users/t/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/
luatex-cache/generic /Users/t/.texlive2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generi
c)
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.152 seconds
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.

(/Users/t/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltjsarti
cle.cls
Document Class: ltjsarticle 2017/03/06 ltjsclasses 

(/Users/t/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja
.sty
(/Users/t/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja
-core.sty
(/Users/t/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatex
base.sty
(/Users/t/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctabl
estack.sty))
(/Users/t/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds
.sty)
(/Users/t/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexc
mds.sty
(/Users/t/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infware
rr.sty)
(/Users/t/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluate
x.sty)
(/Users/t/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.s
ty))
(/Users/t/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.st
y
(/Users/t/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.
tex
(/Users/t/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils
.tex
(/Users/t/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.t
ex))))
(/Users/t/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegsh
i.sty)(load cache: /Users/t/.texlive2016/texmf-var/luatexja/ltj-cid-auto
-adobe-japan1.luc)
(/Users/t/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-base
.sty)
(/Users/t/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-late
x.sty
(/Users/t/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/
lltjfont.sty
(/Users/t/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def)
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \patchcmd 

l.31 ...ame TU\string\textasteriskcentered\endcsname
                                                  {\char}{\ltjalchar}{}{}
?
```

\listfiles output:

```
 *File List*
ltjsarticle.cls    2017/03/06 ltjsclasses 
luatexja.sty    2016/05/12 Japanese Typesetting with Lua(La)TeX
luatexja-core.sty    2016/05/15 Core of LuaTeX-ja
luatexbase.sty    2015/10/04 v1.3 luatexbase interface to LuaTeX 
ctablestack.sty    2015/10/01 v1.0 Catcode table stable support
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
ltj-base.sty    2016/05/15
ltj-latex.sty    2017/03/12 LaTeX support of LuaTeX-ja
lltjfont.sty    2017/04/01 Patch to NFSS2 for LuaTeX-ja
   tuenc.def    2017/02/22 v2.0g Standard LaTeX file
everysel.sty    2011/10/28 v1.2 EverySelectfont Package (MS)
lltjdefs.sty    2016/05/05 Default font settings of LuaTeX-ja
lltjcore.sty    2017/03/12 Patch to LaTeX2e Kernel for LuaTeX-ja
etoolbox.sty    2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
lltjp-geometry.sty    2016/10/06 Patch to geometry for LuaTeX-ja with vertical 
writing mode
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
luatexja-compat.sty    2015/05/09 Compatibility with pTeX
 ***********
```

Comment: This compiles for me without problems (having the latest TL 2016 state before recent freeze)

Comment: Compiles for me with an up-to-date TL2016 as well as a TL2017.

Comment: This does not comples for me neither on a Mac nor Linux machine.  I use the latest (freezed) TL2016.

Comment: Please add `\listfiles` to your input: there is almost certainly an old file about somewhere. (Like the others, I have no issue with this demo file.)

Comment: @JosephWright: Thanks, I added the output of \listfiles at the end.

Comment: I tried to compile the code on another machine and had no luck.  @JosephWright: I'm wondering if you could post output of \listfiles on your machine.

Comment: The problem is that on your system everyhook.sty seems to be missing, and it would load etoolbox.

Comment: Compared with mine you are missing:  `everyhook.sty jslogo.sty lltjp-stfloats.sty stfloats.sty svn-prov.sty`

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer and @Thruston. After installing `everyhook` and `svn-prov`, I could successfully compile the file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved updating the needed packages.